# KDCircularProgress how to fix bug with restart?

Tags: ios, swift

I try to use [KDCircularProgress](https://github.com/kaandedeoglu/KDCircularProgress) to represent progress of task in application and i need to be able to refresh it and run again from the beginning several times, but I couldn't do this because it has built-in bug - when i launch a test project and press "Animate" it begins animation and when i press again it stops, and if I press animate third time it doesnt begin animation but it stucks.

Maybe someone know, how to do fix it ?

Answer (score 1):

Sorry for seeing this too late.

The test project's animate button fires the method

```
public func animateToAngle(toAngle: Int, duration: NSTimeInterval, completion: ((Bool) -> Void)?)
```

it basically starts from the current angle and animates to target angle in a given duration.

`KDCircularProgress` also has a method called

```
public func animateFromAngle(fromAngle: Int, toAngle: Int, duration: NSTimeInterval, completion: ((Bool) -> Void)?)
```

where you can pass in your start angle as well, in your case you can pass 0 as the start angle and it will restart every time.

And please consider opening Github issues in the future.